# How to create a new block in bigchain db?

Tags: node.js, bigchaindb

I'm using bigchain db in our project. Currently we are using transaction model to create assets and transfer it. But now we want to implement block model. When I go through the documentation I can't find how to create a block? Is there any specific url or any function or do we have to use same url as like for transaction model for example http://ourserver.com:8080/api/v1/ ? Can any one help me in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Bitcoin, one submits a transaction to a BigchainDB network and then it's up to the network (i.e. the nodes in the network) to put that transaction in a block (or not, if the transaction is invalid).

Comment: Can you please provide me the url how and when the block is created in bigchain db. It will be really very useful to us.

Comment: An external user (who sends a transaction to a BigchainDB network) cannot create a block manually. That's not how BigchainDB works (or Bitcoin, or any other blockchain that I know of). In BigchainDB version 1.3, you can find the code for block creation in https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/blob/v1.3.0/bigchaindb/pipelines/block.py . In BigchainDB-with-Tendermint (coming soon), Tendermint Core takes care of creating blocks.

Comment: Thank you Troy McConaghy